# openGL Math book to learn matrix rotations/projection frustum settings, etc

Tags: c, math, opengl, matrix, projection

I'm searching for a great-explained book to learn openGL matrix operations, frustum generation (something like http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html but with a greater coverage on homogeneous coordinates and explained a little better), matrix operations, etc... 3D oriented as you already got it

I'm trying to dive into the 3D thing with openGL and I want a strong mathematical background first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look into Carnegie Mellon University's lectures on [Intro to Computer Graphics](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15462-s12/www/).
CMU has great tutorials but doesn't totally give out the "chalkboard" solutions (examples done in lecture hours)

If you wanna find those too, then I recommend http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~fussell/courses/cs384g/schedule.shtml

Here are some more

- http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4620/2011fa/lectures/practicum02.pdf
- http://programmedlessons.org/VectorLessons/index.html
- http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials\
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix
- http://cs.fit.edu/~wds/classes/graphics/Transform/transform/

Keep in mind that some other mathematical and algorithmic stuff such as [Convolution](http://www.roborealm.com/help/Convolution.php) and [QuadTrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), [kdTrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) and [bsp trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) are a must to learn if you are actually looking for a "strong background" but you can do so concurrently as you dive into more of OpenGL

And of course then there is the main 3D beauty of OpenGL - [Ray Tracing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing_%28graphics%29) which is the technique by which simple physics and terms involving lighting objects (attenuation, shadow, refraction, reflection, diffuse, ambient, specular) are important to know.
Here is a little insight into that from one of the classes I took 
http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse457/12sp/lectures/ray-tracing.pdf

Hope all of that helps